# Can't get Composer to load classes when using a file repository

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I'm a PHP novice and just trying to create a package ("`simple-php`"), and then an example project ("`example-php`") that uses the package.

#### simple-php (the package)

`simple-php` has a composer file:

```
{
    "name": "simple/simple-php",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Simple\\" : "src/" }
    }
}
```

Inside `simple-php` is:

```
src/
  HelloWorld.php
composer.json
```

And `HelloWorld.php` is:

```php
namespace Simple;

class HelloWorld
{
    public function __construct(
    )
}
```

#### example-php (the client of the package)

The file structure is:

```
index.php
composer.json
```

`composer.json` includes:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../simple-php"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "simple/simple-php": "0.0.1"
    }
}
```

I ran `php composer.phar install` on this and got, in `composer.lock`:

```
...
        {
            "name": "simple/simple-php",
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "dist": {
                "type": "path",
                "url": "../simple-php",
                "reference": "18171b07ac196fb22d8d95578be916e7897d003e"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "Simple\\": "src/"
                }
            },
            "transport-options": {
                "relative": true
            }
        },
...
```

So now in `index.php` I do:

```
...
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
new Simple\HelloWorld();
```

`vendor/autoload.php` exists, btw, and it contains:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit661a24b81ca7aae7b7471c810ee626fa::getLoader();
```

But when I run the page I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Simple\HelloWorld' not found in /var/www/html/index.php:21

I guess I'm not setting up some sort of namespace correctly, but I can't see it. How can I load the `HelloWorld` class?

I'm using the Docker `php:7.2-apache` image.

Comment: Can you show what is inside the `vendor/autoload.php` file?

Comment: Thanks for replying - I added it, but I don't think there's a lot there... maybe you need to see some other files?

Comment: Did you have uploaded this composer in any repo or git? if possible can you share it.

Comment: No, it's just a file based package. You can see that in the `repositories` section in the example. Should be easy to replicate because I think there's just two files in the package and I listed the contents.

Comment: I can try to upload later if it's helpful.

Comment: I have checked, its working fine but you did a mistake in `HelloWorld.php` file, missed constructor bracket, change it to `public function __construct() {}`

Comment: check this out, i have created for you https://github.com/turivishal/simple-php-composer

Comment: Thanks. It still doesn't work for me, with the change to `HelloWorld`. I ran `composer update` too, in the `example-php` folder. Your `example-php/composer.lock` is the same also. The other thing is that I'm running this in docker with `php:7.2-apache` with the /opt folder pointing to the folder containing both `example-php` and `simple-php`. Maybe there's some resolution problem there.

Comment: Okay and also you can check permissions of folder and files..

Comment: Gah! I tried running it with the docker CLI image instead of the Apache one, and it worked. Then I realised - I wasn't providing the `simple-php` into the Apache container. I'll create an answer in case anyone else has this.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem was: I was using the Docker image with Apache, and I wasn't providing the root folder containing `example-php` and `simple-php`.**

Before I was inside the `example-php` folder and running:

```
docker run -d -p 9010:80 --name php-apache -v "$PWD":/var/www/html php:7.2-apache
```

The problem was the `-v` switch. I changed to:

```
docker run -d -p 9010:80 --name php-apache -v "$PWD/..":/var/www/html php:7.2-apache
```

(and then using the qualifier path of `example-php` when testing)

... and that fixed it.

Thanks to @turivishal for his help in debugging.